# how to match date range with multiple date range in excel along with ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I have two excel sheets, I am trying to find all user details along with request IDs that are accessed on a particular date and time range.

Sheet 1: Request

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User | Request ID | Startdate | enddate | Business reason |
| 100 | 1234567 | Jul 01, 2022 03:24:11 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:11 | SRQ123456 |
| 101 | 1234568 | Jul 01, 2022 06:24:11 | Jul 01, 2022 08:24:11 | CHG123456 |

Sheet 2: Access details

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OBJECTNAME | ACTION | ACCESSBY | ACCESSTIME |
| Business User | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 05:59:12 |
| Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:05:20 |
| Roles Add Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:32 |
| SFA | Delete | 101 | Jul 01, 2022 06:24:12 |

Tried the below code result to find out the record within the date range but I am not able to get the entire row details of sheet1:Request. I have used Name manager from the formula to store the value of Startdate, enddate, and User.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Startdate,"<="&D3,enddate,">="&D3,User,C3)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Sheet 2: Access details

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OBJECTNAME | ACTION | ACCESSBY | ACCESSTIME |  |
| Business User | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 05:59:12 | Yes |
| Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:05:20 | Yes |
| Roles Add Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:32 | No |
| SFA | Delete | 101 | Jul 01, 2022 06:24:12 | Yes |

The expected output in Sheet2 should be as below

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OBJECTNAME | ACTION | ACCESSBY | ACCESSTIME |  | User | Request ID | Startdate | enddate | Business reason |
| Business User | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 05:59:12 | Yes | 100 | 1234567 | Jul 01, 2022 03:24:11 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:11 | SRQ123456 |
| Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:05:20 | Yes | 100 | 1234567 | Jul 01, 2022 03:24:11 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:11 | SRQ123456 |
| Roles Add Workflow | Update | 100 | Jul 01, 2022 06:10:32 | No | Record not matched |  |  |  |  |
| SFA | Delete | 101 | Jul 01, 2022 06:24:12 | Yes | 100 | 1234568 | Jul 01, 2022 06:24:11 | Jul 01, 2022 08:24:11 | CHG123456 |

Comment: XLOOKUP, FILTER should work for you. Post data as text table so that we can copy.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.  And also show your source data as text which can be copy/pasted.  Take a look at this [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), and post the results as "code" for proper formatting.